# How to create apple push notification banner with big image

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

How to create notification banner with app icon and big image in iOS

Comment: Here you go https://medium.com/@tsif/ios-10-rich-push-notifications-with-media-attachments-a54dc86586c2

Answer (score 2):

**OS setup**

**1. Create a Notification Service Extension**

Within your project, you must create a Service Extension. A Service Extension allows for the modification of a notification to include rich media. To add a notification service extension, click on **File > New > Target** and select Notification Service Extension.

[image]

**2. Setting up Notification Service Extension**

Since the Notification Service Extension has its own bundle id, it must be set up with its own App ID and provisioning profile. Please verify through the Apple Developer Service.

**3. Add the following code to Notification Service Extension**

While you are free to implement your own method within the Notification Service Extension, you will need to make sure that your code is correctly handling the media that is being sent with Leanplum. The key that is associated with the rich media in the Leanplum Payload is: LP_URL.

**Swift code -**

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
    var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
        let imageKey = "LP_URL"
        self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        // MARK: - Leanplum Rich Push
        if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
            let userInfo = request.content.userInfo;

            // LP_URL is the key that is used from Leanplum to
            // send the image URL in the payload.
            //
            // If there is no LP_URL in the payload than
            // the code will still show the push notification.
            if userInfo[imageKey] == nil {
                contentHandler(bestAttemptContent);
                return;
            }

            // If there is an image in the payload,
            // download and display the image.
            if let attachmentMedia = userInfo[imageKey] as? String {
                let mediaUrl = URL(string: attachmentMedia)
                let LPSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
                LPSession.downloadTask(with: mediaUrl!, completionHandler: { temporaryLocation, response, error in
                    if let err = error {
                        print("Leanplum: Error with downloading rich push: \(String(describing: err.localizedDescription))")
                        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent);
                        return;
                    }

                    let fileType = self.determineType(fileType: (response?.mimeType)!)
                    let fileName = temporaryLocation?.lastPathComponent.appending(fileType)

                    let temporaryDirectory = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName!)

                    do {
                        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: temporaryLocation!, to: temporaryDirectory)
                        let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: temporaryDirectory, options: nil)

                        bestAttemptContent.attachments = [attachment];
                        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent);
                        // The file should be removed automatically from temp
                        // Delete it manually if it is not
                        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: temporaryDirectory.path) {
                            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: temporaryDirectory)
                        }
                    } catch {
                        print("Leanplum: Error with the rich push attachment: \(error)")
                        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent);
                        return;
                    }
                }).resume()

            }
        }
    }

    override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
        // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
        // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
        if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
            contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Leanplum Rich Push
    func determineType(fileType: String) -> String {
        // Determines the file type of the attachment to append to URL.
        if fileType == "image/jpeg" {
            return ".jpg";
        }
        if fileType == "image/gif" {
            return ".gif";
        }
        if fileType == "image/png" {
            return ".png";
        } else {
            return ".tmp";
        }
    }

}
```

**4. Update [didReceiveRemoteNotification** 
Please make sure to update the application instance method didReceiveRemoteNotification so that it does execute the download of the rich media. See below for a simple example.

**Swift -**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                         didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                         fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(.newData)
}
```

**5. Create a Rich Push from our Dashboard** 
After implementing the code above, you are free to create a rich push notification from our dashboard. Make sure to try it out on a registered test device before sending to users.

```
Set a dynamic image for Rich push messages (beta)
```

Once you are enabled for the rich-push beta feature, you can use Jinja syntax to set a rich push image that changes based on a parameter value for a triggered push notification.

Create a new Push notification message.

Set the URL of the image using new syntax Jinja to include your parameter.

```
https://myimages.com/destinations/cities/{{parameter['dest_code']}}.jpg
```

[image]

Make sure you use brackets around the parameter name (see 'dest_code' above).

**3 . Trigger the push notification off the event whose parameter matches your image URL.**

[image]

Android event with parameter example:

```
HashMap<String, Object> paramsFlight = new HashMap<String, Object>();
paramsFlight.put("dest_code", "Varna");
Leanplum.track("flight_search", paramsFlight);
```

iOS event with parameter example:

```
Leanplum.track("flight_search", withParameters: ["dest_code": "Varna"])
```

4. Test your new push notification on a real device before sending to users!

**Things to note:**

1. If the image does not exist, the push will be sent without the image. The image is resolved on the app, so the push will still be sent, but the image URL will not return an image.
2. If the parameter ("dest_code" in this example) is not provided in the event, the push will not be sent. Failing to provide the right parameter with the event will cause the Jinja customization to fail, which causes the entire message to not send.

Answer (score 2):

It's called "Richview Notification"

- You can simply turn your APNS into Richview by adding keys.

  "mutable-content": 1, 
  "category: "richview"
- You can also fire Local Richview for the testing purpose also.
- You have to add to targets for it

1) Notification Content Extension

2) Service Extension

- Here are the details of how it works:

First of all

```
import UserNotifications
```

Ask the user to allow push notifications

Call this in your `override func viewDidLoad() {`

```
    requestPermissionsWithCompletionHandler { (granted) -> (Void) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if granted {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is the function that asks for permission

```
private func requestPermissionsWithCompletionHandler(completion: ((Bool) -> (Void))? ) {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert]) {[weak self] (granted, error) in

            guard error == nil else {

                completion?(false)
                return
            }

            if granted {

                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                self?.setNotificationCategories() // set your action categories

            }

            completion?(granted)
        }
    }
```

Here is how you can set your categories

```
    private func setNotificationCategories() {

              let btnAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "action", title: "Press", options: [])
        let textInput = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "comment", title: "Comment", options: [])

        let actionCategory =  UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "actionCategory", actions: [btnAction,textInput], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([lactionCategory])

        }
```

Create one function that fire local notification

```
func sendNotification() -> Void {

    notificationBodyField.resignFirstResponder()

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Local Notifications"
    content.subtitle =  "Subtitle"

    if  let characters = notificationBodyField.text?.characters, let text = notificationBodyField.text , characters.count > 0 {

        content.body = text
    }
    else {
        content.body = notificationBodyString
    }

    content.categoryIdentifier = "local"


    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gm", withExtension: "jpg")
    // download your image and provide local URL here 

    let attachment = try! UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "image", url: url!, options: [:])

    content.attachments = [attachment]

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 2, repeats: false)

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "localNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {[weak self] (error) in

        guard error == nil else {

            return
        }
    }

}
```

Call this function in your `override func viewDidLoad() {` after above code and you can call it on any action also it is depend on the requirement.

For more information, you can refer

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications

http://thecodeninja.tumblr.com/post/125772843855/notifications-in-ios-9-quick-inline-reply-for

I hope this will help you :)